# Prove that a second order diff. eq. has only two linearly independent solutions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ be two continuous functions. Prove that the second order linear equation $$y'' + p(t)y' + q(t)y = 0$$ has two, and only two linearly independent solutions.

$\textbf{Sketch of Proof:}$

D$^2$y + pDy + qy = 0

(D$^2$ + pD + q)y = 0

Let L = D$^2$ + pD + q

L is a linear operator, Ly = 0

Claim: {c$_1$y$_1$ + c$_2$y$_2$} are all the solutions

Because L is a linear operator $\rightarrow$ L(c$_1$y$_1$ + c$_2$y$_2$) = L(c$_1$y$_1$) + L(c$_2$y$_2$)

= c$_1$L(y$_1$) + c$_2$L(y$_2$)

Since c$_1$y$_1$ + c$_2$y$_2$ is a solution and L(c$_1$y$_1$ + c$_2$y$_2$) = 0 $\rightarrow$

c$_1$L(y$_1$) = 0 and c$_2$L(y$_2$) = 0

*I know I need to prove that c$_1$ and c$_2$ are 0, but I'm not sure how to prove that this is the only case.*

Comment: Care to show us what you have tried?

Comment: I know one solution will be y(t) = 0, but I was thinking I could either integrate it or change it to a first order equation and then try to solve.

Comment: Without solving the equation, it's easy to show that the solutions of this equation form a vector space. It's more complicated to show that the space is of dimension 2. The trick is to use Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem, that show that the solutions are uniquely determinated by the values of y(0) and y'(0)

Comment: @user114634 Showing that if you have 2 different solutions the 3rd one must be a linear combination of the other two is just a simple case of a proof by contradiction. 0 is indeed a solution, but not a useful one, as it does not generate other solutions through linear combinations. We need to show there are at least two nontrivial solutions (that's the tricky part).

Comment: @Lurco : is the proof by contradiction of this fact really simple? I don't see an easy way to get a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that this refers to an open $t$-interval $\Omega$ with $0\in\Omega$. According to the standard existence theorem (extended to second-order ODEs) there are two solutions $y_1$, $y_2:\>\Omega\to{\mathbb R}$ realizing the particular initial values 
$$y_1(0)=1, \quad y_1'(0)=0,\qquad{\rm resp.}\qquad y_2(0)=0,\quad y_2'(0)=1\ .$$
The existence theorem guarantees this first for some neighborhood of $0$, but in the case of a linear ODE the two solutions can actually be extended to all of $\Omega$. The two functions $y_1$ and $y_2$ are obviously linearly independent. It follows that the solution space ${\cal L}$, which is a vector space in our case, has dimension $\geq 2$.

Now let $t\mapsto y(t)$ be an arbitrary solution. Then the function
$$y_*(t):=y(t)- y(0)y_1(t)-y'(0)y_2(t)$$
is also a solution, and in addition satisfies $y_*(0)=y_*'(0)=0$. But the zero solution satisfies these two conditions as well, and by the uniqueness part of the main theorem about ODE's it follows that in fact $y_*(t)\equiv0$. This proves that $y_1$, $y_2$ generate all of ${\cal L}$, whence ${\rm dim}({\cal L})\leq2$ as well.

Comment: By a standard existence theorem you mean the Picard-Lindelöf theorem? Why does it guarantee the existence of 2 solutions and in this form?

Comment: @Lurco: See my edit.